# authentication form using Electron (Atom shell) and PHP+mysql server only

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, authentication, electron

I want to authenticate users of my app, I know how to do it using php on client but Electron can't use PHP at client side

Is there a way to authenticate users from mysql in Electron's app?

I need something like `$_SESSION` (PHP)

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

First never authenticate on the client side. Always on server side. Use [OAuth´s PHP Implementation](http://php.net/manual/de/book.oauth.php) or write you own implementation. Then simply use node´s native https request and return json from your server, PHP script. Please do a lot more research on application design and security.